# Preventing PHP from throwing errors and exceptions when testing for a bad SoapClient connection in Behat

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap, automation, behat

We are working on setting up a SOAP server and I am specifically working on creating automated tests for it in Behat. The problem I am running into is that I am trying to test authentication of connections to the SOAP server and specifically trying to write tests that make sure that it fails to connect when no username and password are provided.

However, every time I run the test without HTTP authentication added in (and WSDL caching disabled intentionally) I get a PHP warning that throws up an error trace all over the console screen.

It is a PHP Warning that reads:

```
PHP Warning:  SoapClient::SoapClient(http://cti.local/api/v1/companies/d1/soap?wsdl): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

I would like to be able to suppress that error and just make sure it returns NULL or negative when declaring the new client. To do this I have tried adding the "@" sign right before the "new" keyword and wrapping the call in a try/catch statement that doesn't throw exceptions. But that doesn't work. I also tried adding the "@" sign at the beginning of the line to no avail.

That was using PHP's built-in SOAP client class. It seemed like an awesome way to go until I ran into this issue. So then, after exhausting all the options I would find, I then tried setting up the Zend SOAP Client and using that. Only to discover that it seems to extend PHP's built-in SoapClient class. So that is not working either.

Unfortunately we are using HTTP auth for all calls to the API, including to the WSDL. Currently I am running a checked out copy of the API locally (since we don't have it setup on an environment yet). I know that when I put in the proper authentication it works fine. But I want to make sure that my automated Behat tests can successfully test and return a test passed message for when I verify that the connection authentication fails.

Sample of connection call:

```
/**
 * SOAP connection initiation.
 *
 * @param string $soapURL
 * @param string $options (optional, no implemented yet)
 *
 * @Given /^I connect to a soap service at "([^"]*)"$/
 */
public function iConnectToASoapServiceAt($soapURL) {
    $this->soapURL = $soapURL;

    try {
        $this->client = @new Zend\Soap\Client($soapURL, $this->options);
        $this->soapFunctions = $this->client->getFunctions();
    }
    catch (\Exception $e) {
        #For testing when it fails we cannot actually throw an error here.
        #throw new Exception("Error connecting to SOAP server.");
    }
}

/**
 * @Given /^soap returns an error$/
 */
public function soapReturnsAnError() {
    if ($this->client !== NULL && $this->soapFunctions !== NULL) {
        throw new Exception("SOAP connection did not fail as expected.");
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas? I need to be able to test both a successful connection and an unsuccessful one in an automated way that won't error out and kill the PHP call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@` only suppresses errors of a single function call.

Try changing the error reporting level before the failed authentication code is executed, and than bring it back afterwards:

```
$level = error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE); 

// your code with failed authentication here

error_reporting($level);
```

Comment: I actually found that a multi-pronged approach was needed. First of all I had to do what you suggest (save the current level, set to 0 before the problem code and then set back to previous level upon completion). I also had to wrap it in try/catch. Then I had to make sure that xdebug was disabled during it. And finally, for good measure in some cases, I had to even set my own error handler that essentially does nothing in most error cases.